# Unable to query Many to Many relationship in Amplify Datastore

Tags: javascript, graphql, aws-amplify, amplifyjs, aws-amplify-sdk-js

I have 2 model with Many-to-Many Relationship. The 2 model is `Order` and `Product`. An `Order` will have many `Product` and `Product` will in many Order.

**My Goal is** : Given a `orderID`, get a list of `productID` in the `Order`

So I followed this [Amplify guide](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/js#many-to-many) to group the into `OrderProducts` , `Order` and `Product` like this `schema.graphql`

```
type Order @model @key(name: "byStore", fields: ["storeID"]) @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read, update, create, delete]}]) {
  id: ID!
  buyer_name: String
  order_total_amount: String
  products: [OrderProducts] @connection(keyName: "byOrder", fields: ["id"])
  created_at: AWSTimestamp
}

type OrderProducts @model @key(name: "byOrder", fields:["orderID", "productID"]) @key(name: "byProduct", fields:["productID", "orderID"]) @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read, update, create, delete]}]){
  id: ID!
  orderID: ID!
  productID: ID!
  order: Order! @connection(fields: ["orderID"])
  product: Product! @connection(fields: ["productID"])
}

type Product @model @key(name: "byStore", fields: ["storeID"]) @auth(rules: [{allow: owner, operations: [create, update, delete]}, {allow: public, provider: iam, operations: [read]}]){
  id: ID!
  product_name: String!
  product_price: String!
  created_at: AWSTimestamp
  orders: [OrderProducts] @connection(keyName: "byProduct", fields:["id"])
}
```

But when I query the OrderProduct model like below, in order to get a List of Products by OrderID:

```
import {  Product, OrderProducts } from '../models';

export const GetAllProductIdByOrderId = async (order) => {
    return await DataStore.query(OrderProducts, op => op.orderID("eq", order.id)) // this is actual orderID
}
```

I get this error as a result:

```
Error: Invalid field for model. field: orderID, model: OrderProducts
```

What I tried:

**Attempt 1**

I tried to add a `queryField` named `getOrderByOrderIDByProductID` in `OrderProducts` like this:

```
type OrderProducts @model @key(name: "byOrder", fields:["orderID", "productID"], queryField: "getOrderByOrderIDByProductID") @key(name: "byProduct", fields:["productID", "orderID"]) @auth(rules: [{allow: private, operations: [read, update, create, delete]}]){
  id: ID!
  orderID: ID!
  productID: ID!
  order: Order! @connection(fields: ["orderID"])
  product: Product! @connection(fields: ["productID"])
}
```

Then `amplify push`, `amplify codegen models`, after all this, I cant import `getOrderByOrderIDByProductID` in my file and get this error

```
warn Attempted import error: 'getOrderByOrderIDByProductID' is not exported from '../models' (imported as 'getOrderByOrderIDByProductID').
```

So I checked my `model/index.js` , it dont have `getOrderByOrderIDByProductID` exported. So dont know what else I can do.

**Attempt 2**

I go to AppSync console, I seen `getOrderByOrderIDByProductID` in my query section, then I tried to run this query:

```
query MyQuery {
  getOrderByOrderIDByProductID(filter: {orderID: {eq: "8649a9da-9ea6-4a30-afe7-6b336a8f853d"}}) {
    items {
      order {
        buyer_name
        createdAt
        id
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then I get the following output:

```
{
  "data": {
    "getOrderByOrderIDByProductID": null
  },
  "errors": [
    {
      "path": [
        "getOrderByOrderIDByProductID"
      ],
      "data": null,
      "errorType": "MappingTemplate",
      "errorInfo": null,
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3,
          "sourceName": null
        }
      ],
      "message": "Expression block '$[query]' requires an expression"
    }
  ]
}
```

I cant get any `productID` from the query and dont know what is the result mean.

I followed the suggestion mention in this [github issue](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-flutter/issues/264#issuecomment-749838631) and reported in github  as well, if you wanna to read a more detail version can read it [here](https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/8139).

**To summarize:**

Only 1 goal: Given an `orderID`, give me a list of `productID` inside the `Order`.

And tell me what I doing wrong, if possible, give me an example. Cause I followed [this example in amplify docs](https://docs.amplify.aws/lib/datastore/relational/q/platform/js#many-to-many) and still having this issue

Comment: Have you had any success with this issue? I am facing the same problem.

Comment: @OleksiyMartynov no success on this yet. I end up using dynamodb by myself